# Speech Recognition, ListView ArrayAdapter: What is the best way to use if("certain word spoken"){ } is there methods i can use?

Tags: android

The Speech Recognition puts all the possibilities into the list view, im just wondering how i can use the values in ListView to use an if("word was spoken"){ "do something" }, do i have to make my own search or is there already methods, proper syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer i was looking for was this:

```
 if(string.contains(" ")){
```

}